# Play asset delivery: How does application upgrade work?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, android-asset-delivery, android-assetpacks

I have an android application with 3 asset packs which are downloaded install time. I have added a file of size 10MB in one of the asset packs.  Asset pack size increased from 30MB to 40MB.

Will the whole APK gets downloaded again? Or Will the pack that got modified gets downloaded? Or Will the file that got added in that asset pack get downloaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will the whole APK gets downloaded again? Or Will the pack that got modified gets downloaded? Or Will the file that got added in that asset pack get downloaded?

NO, only the modified asset pack will be downloaded and sometimes only the new file inside this asset pack will be downloaded (because Google Play have  delta patching).